# How to set namespace on @XmlAnyElement with DomHandler?

Tags: xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, moxy, jaxb2

I have a simple JAXB annotated class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    @XmlAnyElement(value = BioHandler.class)
    public String bio;
}
```

The `BioHandler` is from Blaise Doughan's [example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html).

I want the `bio` field to have the same namespace than all other elements. Therefore I create a `package-info.java` in the package of the class:

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, 
           namespace = "http://timomeinen.de/demo/namespace") 
package com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.batchjobs.exports.saminventar.timo;
```

This works for the root element, but not for the `bio` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer xmlns="http://timomeinen.de/demo/namespace">
   <bio xmlns="">my bio</bio>
</customer>
```

Instead the marshaller generates an empty `xmlns=""` attribute.

How can I define the namespace?

---

Edit 1:

I was able to solve the problem by defining the namespace in the DomHandler. Instead of `<bio>` I prepend `<bio xmlns="http://timomeinen.de/demo/namespace">` to the marshalled XML:

```
public class BioHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {

    private static final String BIO_START_TAG = "<bio xmlns=\"http://timomeinen.de/demo/namespace\">";
    private static final String BIO_END_TAG = "</bio>";

    private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter();

    public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
    }

    public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
        String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(BIO_START_TAG) + BIO_START_TAG.length();
        int endIndex = xml.indexOf(BIO_END_TAG);
        return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = BIO_START_TAG + n.trim() + BIO_END_TAG;
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this seems to me like a hack. What is the correct way of defining the namespace? Why is the default namespace defined in `package-info.java` ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Is a namespace prefix an option?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer xmlns:timo="http://timomeinen.de/demo/namespace">
   <timo:bio>my bio</timo:bio>
</customer>
```

A namespace without prefix **should** work however, not sure why it doesn't.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I validate against a XSD schema and the validation does not work with mixed namespaces.